# How to fit the matrix in the text block?

Tags: math-mode, equations, formatting

So I was writing some solution and determinant just flows out of the bo. how to fix this?

I am using Dyan Yu's Sty file which can be found on github by a quick google search.

```
\documentclass[paper=6.125in:8.25in,twoside,openany,pagesize=pdftex,10pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[retro,cabin,sleek,nosecthm]{dylanadi}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\title{KVPY SA Mathematics 2022}
\author{Ayan Khan}
\date{\today}
\date{\today}
\changemaincolor{blue}
\changesecondcolor{red}

\begin{document}

\begingroup % figure out how to put logo in
\notofont
\color{\secondcolor}
\let\newpage\relax%
\dylantitle
\endgroup

\newpage

%\tableofcontents
\newpage
\begin{problem}
\newline \newline
Let A be a matrix defined as $A = \displaystyle \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{1} & a_{2} & a_{3} & \dots  & a_{n} \\
    a_{n} & a_{1} & x_{2} & \dots  & a_{n-1} \\
    a_{n-1} & a_{n} & x_{1} & \dots  & a_{n-2} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    a_{2} & a_{3} & x_{4} & \dots  & a_{1}
\end{bmatrix}$ If $g(x)$ is equal to $\displaystyle a_{1}+a_{2}x+a_{3}x^{2}+\cdots+a_{n}x^{n-1}$ and $a_{i}$, where i = 1 to n, denote the $n^{th}$ complex root of unity. If $A ={\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{n} g(\alpha_{i})}$ and $b_{0}=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{6}$ and $\displaystyle b_{n} = \frac{b_{n}^{2}-5}{2(b_{n}+2)}$, $\displaystyle \forall n > 0,$ then porve that $\displaystyle b_{n} = cot\Big(\frac{2^{n-3}\pi}{3}\Big)-2k$.
\end{problem}

\begin{solution}
As the coefficients of $g(x)$ from the Determinant $A$, we shall solve this by assuming an another Determinant $\displaystyle Y =\displaystyle \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & \alpha_{1} & \alpha_{1}^{2} & \dots  & \alpha_{1}^{n-1} \\
    1 & \alpha_{2} & \alpha_{2}^{2} & \dots  & \alpha_{2}^{n-1} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    1 & \alpha_{n} & \alpha_{n}^{2} & \dots  & \alpha_{n}^{n-1}
\end{vmatrix}$
\newline Now,
$A \times Y =\begin{vmatrix}
    a_{1}+a_{2}\alpha_{1}+a_{3}\alpha_{1}^{2}+\cdots+a_{n}\alpha_{1}^{n-1} & a_{1}+a_{2}\alpha_{2}+a_{n}\alpha_{2}^{2}+\cdots+a_{n}\alpha_{1}^{n-1} & \alpha_{1}^{2} & \dots  & \alpha_{1}^{n-1} \\
    1 & \alpha_{2} & \alpha_{2}^{2} & \dots  & \alpha_{2}^{n-1} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    1 & \alpha_{n} & \alpha_{n}^{2} & \dots  & \alpha_{n}^{n-1}
\end{vmatrix}$
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Making equations containing big determinant displayed, introducing new notations to shorten the entries of determinant, etc.

Comment: *… can be found on github by a quick google search.* Sure, make it difficult for people trying to help you …

Comment: I support the idea of introducing short hand notations. I.e. a determinant is not the best place to put a sum (which could be shortened); rather it's an opprotunity to show structure or pattern of the determinant, which is lost in the current writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shall focus on the final code chunk, i.e.,

```
\newline Now,
$A \times Y =\begin{vmatrix}
    a_{1}+a_{2}\alpha_{1}+a_{3}\alpha_{1}^{2}+\cdots+a_{n}\alpha_{1}^{n-1} & a_{1}+a_{2}\alpha_{2}+a_{n}\alpha_{2}^{2}+\cdots+a_{n}\alpha_{1}^{n-1} & \alpha_{1}^{2} & \dots  & \alpha_{1}^{n-1} \\
    1 & \alpha_{2} & \alpha_{2}^{2} & \dots  & \alpha_{2}^{n-1} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    1 & \alpha_{n} & \alpha_{n}^{2} & \dots  & \alpha_{n}^{n-1}
\end{vmatrix}$
```

The only half-way sensible way to typeset is to use shortcuts for the elements in the (1,1) and (1,2) positions of the matrix and to spell out the shortcuts later on.

Do also please make a habit of using true display math mode instead of `$\displaystyle...$` constructs.

The framelines in the following screenshot are there because the `geometry` package is loaded with the option `showframe`.

[image]

(Off-topic: I think I can spot two mistakes in the final equation.)

```
\documentclass[paper=6.125in:8.25in,10pt]{scrbook}

%%\usepackage[retro,cabin,sleek,nosecthm]{dylanadi}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1.5cm, hmargin=1cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\textcolor{red}{\Large Before}

Now,
    $A \times Y =
    \begin{vmatrix}
        a_{1}+a_{2}\alpha_{1}+a_{3}\alpha_{1}^{2}+\cdots+a_{n}\alpha_{1}^{n-1} & 
        a_{1}+a_{2}\alpha_{2}+a_{n}\alpha_{2}^{2}+\cdots+a_{n}\alpha_{1}^{n-1} & 
        \alpha_{1}^{2} & \dots  & \alpha_{1}^{n-1} \\
        1 & \alpha_{2} & \alpha_{2}^{2} & \dots  & \alpha_{2}^{n-1} \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        1 & \alpha_{n} & \alpha_{n}^{2} & \dots  & \alpha_{n}^{n-1}
    \end{vmatrix}$
    

\bigskip\noindent
\textcolor{red}{\Large After}
\medskip

Now,
\[
\det K\equiv \det (A \times Y) =\begin{vmatrix}
    \kappa_{11} & \kappa_{12} & \alpha_{1}^{2} & \dots  & \alpha_{1}^{n-1} \\
    1 & \alpha_{2} & \alpha_{2}^{2} & \dots  & \alpha_{2}^{n-1} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    1 & \alpha_{n} & \alpha_{n}^{2} & \dots  & \alpha_{n}^{n-1}
\end{vmatrix}
\]
where
\begin{align*}
\kappa_{11}&=a_{1}+a_{2}\alpha_{1}+a_{3}\alpha_{1}^{2}+\cdots+a_{n}\alpha_{1}^{n-1} \\ 
\shortintertext{and}
\kappa_{12}&=a_{1}+a_{2}\alpha_{2}+a_{n}\alpha_{2}^{2}+\cdots+a_{n}\alpha_{1}^{n-1}\,.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```